# Scrollable Bar Chart in Achart engine in android

Tags: android

I want to make scrollable bar chart as x-axis value is to large, my layout is

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/chart1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal" />
    </ScrollView>
```

and in java I have set property

```
    renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
    renderer.setInScroll(true);
```

If I remove scroll view then chart display properly, but if I add linear layout inside scrollview than chart is invisible.
if I set renderer.setPanEnabled(true,true), then also same problem occur.
if I set renderer.setInScroll(true), then also same problem occur.

Please help me to come out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full `main.xml` example, with `ScrollView` and 3 Button. I hope it's help for you.
I think the problem you not put the scroll view to a wrapper (like linear layout). I should not put view property from Java code, if it is a static content.
This is my example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <ScrollView 
      android:layout_height="110px" 
      android:id="@+id/scrollView1" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent">
      <LinearLayout 
          android:orientation="vertical" 
          android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
          <Button 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:id="@+id/button2" 
              android:text="Button" />
          <Button 
              android:text="Button" 
              android:id="@+id/button3" 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
          <Button 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:id="@+id/button1" 
              android:text="Button" />           
      </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply but my problem is with achartengine

Answer (score 0):

Remove ScrollView and write xml like:

```
 <LinearLayout 
              android:id="@+id/chart1"
              android:orientation="horizontal" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
              android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal" />
```

Now use `setPanEnabled(true, true);`